# Select data from three tables?

Tags: sql, select

How can I write a SQL statement to select data from three tables?

Comment: The general principle is to use joins. Give us some more details on the table structures and relationships and we can flesh out an answer for you.

Comment: Provide more information

Comment: Please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  I'd also suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a join

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 ON (table_2.table_1_id = table_1.table_1_id)
JOIN table_3 ON (table_3.table_1_id = table_1.table_1_id)
```

This will require that each table has a table_1_id key and that there is an entry in each table.

You can use a LEFT JOIN if table_2 or table_3 may not have data but you still want to show the data from table_1

Answer (score 7):

Here's a very general example:

```
SELECT KEYVAL, A.OTHER_COL, B.ANOTHER_COL, C.YET_ANOTHER_COL
  FROM TABLE_A A
  INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
    USING (KEYVAL)
  INNER JOIN TABLE_C C
    USING (KEYVAL)
```

If your database doesn't support USING you could say:

```
SELECT A.KEYVAL, A.OTHER_COL, B.ANOTHER_COL, C.YET_ANOTHER_COL
  FROM TABLE_A A
  INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
    ON (B.KEYVAL = A.KEYVAL)
  INNER JOIN TABLE_C C
    ON (C.KEYVAL = A.KEYVAL)
```

Or you could say

```
SELECT A.KEYVAL, A.OTHER_COL, B.ANOTHER_COL, C.YET_ANOTHER_COL
  FROM TABLE_A,
       TABLE_B,
       TABLE_C
  WHERE B.KEYVAL = A.KEYVAL AND
        C.KEYVAL = A.KEYVAL
```

but I think the latter is less clear.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: +1 for using the standard ANSI JOINs (INNER JOIN etc.) ! If you use table aliases in your column list, you should define those table aliases in your FROM and INNER JOIN, too!

Comment: Note that the `USING` syntax for the joins is not universal across all RDBMS platforms.

Comment: @Joe: I added an alternative that uses ON clauses.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [Join(SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) clause.

You can join your first table with your second. Then you third table to your first or second table.

Ex:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A
JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.ID = TABLE_B.ID
JOIN TABLE_C ON TABLE_C.ID = TABLE_B.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

If your tables have the same schema and you want to essentially concatenate the rows from each table then you should think about a `UNION` query.

```
SELECT
Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT
Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT
Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM Table3
```

If you want to include related data from each table in a single row of your result set then you should look at using `INNER JOIN`s and / or `OUTER JOIN`s.

```
SELECT Table1.Field1, Table2.Field2, Table3.Field3
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field1=Table2.Field1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 on Table1.Field3=Table3.Field3
```

We'll need more information from you, though, in order to give you a definitive answer including which RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Using join you can select data from three tables

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
JOIN 
  table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name
JOIN 
  table3 ON table3.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

Answer (score -3):

select Data From Three Table like Joins on Country State and city

select country.country,country.countryid,countrystate.state,
 countrystatecity.city from country
inner join countrystate
on(country.countryid=countrystate.countryid)
inner join countrystatecity
on(countrystate.stateid=countrystatecity.stateid)