# Select data from three different tables with null data

Tags: sql

I am new in Sql. My question is `how to get data from three different tables with null values.`

I have tried a query as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM [USER]
JOIN [Location] ON ([Location].UserId = [USER].Id)
JOIN [ParentChild] ON ([ParentChild].UserId = [USER].Id) WHERE ParentId=7
```

which I find from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301853/select-data-from-three-tables).

Its working fine but, it not fetches all and each data associated with the `ParentId`

Something like it only fetches data which are available in all tables, but also omits some data which not available in Location tables but it comes under the given ParentId.

For example:

```
+----------+-------------+
|  UserId  |   ParentId  |
+----------+-------------+
|    1     |      7      |
+----------+-------------+
|    8     |      7      |
+----------+-------------+
```

For userId 8, there is data available in Location table,so it fetches all data. But there is no data for userId 1 available in Location table, so the query didn't work for this.

But I want all and every data. 
If there is no data for userId then it can return only null columns.
Is it possible ??

hope everyone can understand my problem.

Comment: Look into `LEFT JOIN` and see if you can use it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want to return a list of users, but some may not have locations then you want to change the type of join from an "Inner Join" (or as you have used the short hand "JOIN") to a "Left Join".

```
SELECT *
FROM [USER]
INNER JOIN [ParentChild] ON ([ParentChild].UserId = [USER].Id) 
LEFT JOIN [Location] ON ([Location].UserId = [USER].Id)
WHERE ParentId=7
```

This doesn't account for users that do not have a parent. If you still want to return users who do not have a parent then you would then need to change the JOIN type to your ParentChild table to a LEFT join also.